# Work with twoo objects list on Jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I will try to explain myself as best I can:

I am developing a kind of social network, in wich there are people registered and you can add as your friends. Once you have friends adds to your list of friends, when you want to list all the users that are in the social network (with Jinja2), I would like to inform somehow which of those users are your friends, for example:

```
{% for user in user_list %}
<tr>
<td> {{ user.username }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The code above will show all the usernames registered on the website. And the code below the usernames of my friends:

```
{% for friend in friends_list %}
<tr>
<td> {{ friend.username }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do something like:

```
{% for user in user_list %}
<tr>
{% if user "is inside" friends_list %}
<td> {{ user.username }}</td>
<td> FRIEND</td>
{% else %}
<td> {{ user.username }}</td>
<td>NO FRIEND</td>
{% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I went through the Jijna2 documentation and I didn't find anything usefull...

Thanks verymuch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use user in friends_list ...

```
{% for user in user_list %}
    <tr>
    {% if user in friends_list %}
        <td> {{ user.username }}</td>
        <td> FRIEND</td>
    {% else %}
        <td> {{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>NO FRIEND</td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!